# What is the best way for URL grouping in Map-reduce job java

Tags: java, algorithm, mapreduce, grouping

I have a huge data set of URLs from various domains. I have to process them via mapreduce so that the URLs with similar pattern are grouped together. For example

```
http://www.agricorner.com/price/onion-prices/
http://www.agricorner.com/price/potato-prices/
http://www.agricorner.com/price/ladyfinder-prices/

http://www.agricorner.com/tag/story/story-1.html
http://www.agricorner.com/tag/story/story-11.html
http://www.agricorner.com/tag/story/story-41.html

https://agrihunt.com/author/ramzan/page/3/
https://agrihunt.com/author/shahban/page/5/
https://agrihunt.com/author/Sufer/page/3/
```

I want to group these URLs based on their pattern i.e., if URLs has similar pattern ( in reducer phase of Map-reduce). The expected output may be like

```
group1, http://www.agricorner.com/price/onion-prices/, http://www.agricorner.com/price/potato-prices/, http://www.agricorner.com/price/ladyfinder-prices/

group2, http://www.agricorner.com/tag/story/story-1.html, http://www.agricorner.com/tag/story/story-11.html, http://www.agricorner.com/tag/story/story-41.html

group3, https://agrihunt.com/author/ramzan/page/3/, https://agrihunt.com/author/shahban/page/5/, https://agrihunt.com/author/Sufer/page/3/
```

It it possible ? Is there any better approach that the supposed one?

**update for similar pattern**:

For above example "/price/ladyfinder-prices", "price/potato-prices/" and "/ladyfinder-prices/" are grouped togather as they have same domain, path up to some level. Same story for other examples.
My scenerious is very close to the one discussed at [github](https://github.com/cfhamlet/os-urlpattern) but how it works for map-reduce ?

Comment: Define in detail what you mean by 'similar pattern '. To me it looks like simple common prefix (prefix-path).

Answer (score 1):

Map each URL to the key with everything after the last `/` removed.

Done. Straightforward, isn't it.

Anything more complicated is likely to fail, and you'll need to carefully consider further rules. For example, you could substitute `\d+` by `0` to capture further patterns. Or detect common formats of dates.

Anyway, write code to assign the same key to everything that should be the same group, and different keys to different groups.